# JavaScript adding integer values onto existing number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable

```
var number = 1;
```

I'm then trying to add a 2 onto a number but not add them together like this.

1 + 2 = 2

but instead I want, to join 2 onto the number so i would get

12

Comment: Yeah i think i wa just over thinking this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `+=` and add 2 as string then again convert it to number

```js
var number = 1;
number += '2';
console.log(Number(number));
```

Comment: Thank you just what I was looking for

Comment: Clear answer. And straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() to convert the value into integer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add an empty string between the numbers like so:

```
var number = 1;
var result = number + "" + 2;
alert(result);
```

Another way it to cast the number to a string using [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
var number = 1;
var result = number.toString() + 2;
alert(result);
```

[Working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/aza8rmjh/)

Comment: Thank you just what I was looking for

Comment: will do when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var number = 1;
var z = parseInt(number) + '2';

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand

```
var number = 1;
number = +(number + '' + 2);
console.log(number)
```